# How can one detect transclusion depth?

Tags: mediawiki-templates

In MediaWiki, is there a standard pattern that you can include in a template body to detect depth of transclusion?

Specifically, let's assume
    Template:Myinfobox
 contains such a pattern that displays "native myinfobox call" for depth 1 transclusion and "transclusion call" otherwise.

Then, if page
    Mypage
 calls
    {{Myinfobox}}
 it should display "native myinfobox call" while any page that calls
    {{Mypage}}
  should display "transclusion call"

Does anyone know such a pattern that does not require the writer of 
    Mypage
 to insert special markup or `<noinclude>` or `<includeonly>` tags?

Comment: As far as I know, no, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointers. I was aware of these but it's good to have them here. Right now I'm resorting to the following trick (using the terminology of my question): I have a `home article` parameter in the Myinfobox that the user of the template must set to the name of the page hosting the Myinfobox direct call. Thus Mypage will contain something like:

```
{{ Myinfobox | … | home article = Mypage | … }}
```

The Myinfobox template tests whether `{{PAGENAME}}` equals `{{{ home article }}}` to determine the message it outputs: "transclusion" in case the 2 values are different, "native" otherwise.

But this is clumsy and places burden on the template user.

Comment: Ah, that's indeed one way we do it, for instance in [`{{langcat}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Langcat).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing. However, you can learn some evil tricks and internals on expansion depth limits and branching at

- https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Advanced_templates
- https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Expansion_depth
- https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Substitution#Multilevel_substitution